# Apply different formula to each of imported table cell

Tags: excel

I'm importing table from web (exchange rate). I can successfully import data, but I have different exchange "multiplier" like 1 USD but 100 JPY. So now to apply this imported data to sheet, I'd would like to separate multiplier and currency to separate columns.

I've tried to use formula like I would do with normal cells:

> =RIGHT(B2;FIND(" ";B2)+1)

Assuming that my data starts in B2 cell. But after this formula applies for each row as for first row, so now for I have "USD" but "0 JPY". How can I force excel to apply formula to each row separately?

[image]

Comment: Use a different formula, e.g. `=MID(B2;FIND(" ";B2)+1;LEN(B2))`.

Comment: Or use Power Query / Get & Transform to split that column by the space delimiter: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-a-column-of-text-power-query-5282d425-6dd0-46ca-95bf-8e0da9539662

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. This formula work for cutting of LEFT side of text, and for right I need to use LEN-FIND. And also I realised that currency is always 3 letters long so I just need RIGHT(A2;3) and all will work fine.